# How to use AnimeJS library on QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, anime.js

in Qt Creator, I was created **QT Quick Application** and with this link [github](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime#getting-started), but with this way :

`import "qrc:/anime-master/lib/anime.js" as Logic`

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("JS")

    Rectangle{
        id: rec1
        width: 100; height: width
        color: "orange"
        x: 200; y: 250
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                getAnime()
            }
        }
    }

    function getAnime(){
        Logic.anime({
                  targets: rec1,
                  translateX: 320
              });
    }
}
```

but I have this error:

`qrc:/anime-master/lib/anime.js:1283: ReferenceError: module is not defined`
in its file : `module.exports = anime;`
and my knowledge of js is little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple answer**: you should use [QML's internal tools](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html) for animations.
**More detailed answer**:

1. You can't just simply use any JS library in QML. They are written for browser usage where JS is a first class citizen. But in QML it is quite limited in functionality.
2. I almost sure that most of animation libraries for JS are based on `setTimeout()` function. There is simply no such function in QML.
3. If you somehow make it work, it will be painfully slow and unstable, because it's wide of the mark.